button hover effect not the same width as the vertical navabr
I am attempting to make it so the on ohver effect for each navbar button highlights the full width of the navbar. Currently it just wraps it in the highlight as if its just highlighting the button component.
this was the CSS I cant seem to adjust it in any way that affects the on hover effect
.menu {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: #4b4376;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    padding: 25px;
}

.menu.open {
    display: flex;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.nav-button, .nav-link {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.nav-button:hover, .nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #594f8c;
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
}

.active {
    background-color: #594f8c;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        width: 200px;
        min-width: 200px;
        position: static;
        height: 100vh;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}


This is what it is affecting
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import "./styles.css";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = ({ isOpen, toggleMenu }) => {
    const openClass = isOpen ? "open" : "";
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <div className={`menu ${openClass}`}>
            <button onClick={toggleMenu} className="nav-button">
                Compose
            </button>
            <Link
                to="/"
                className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === '/' ? 'active' : ''}`}
            >
                Inbox
            </Link>
            <Link
                to="/sent"
                className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === '/sent' ? 'active' : ''}`}
            >
                Sent
            </Link>
            <Link
                to="/deleted"
                className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === '/deleted' ? 'active' : ''}`}
            >
                Deleted
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {
    isOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    toggleMenu: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Navbar;


The current hover effect in use
